# Windows 10 install not recognizing Samsung 850 Evo m.2 hard drive

Tags: windows-10, desktop-computer, windows-installation, m.2

I just built a PC from scratch and I'm trying to clean-install Windows 10 on the Samsung 850 Evo m.2 on my motherboard. This is my only hard drive connected. I'm trying to install via Windows 10 USB stick. When I get to the part in the Windows 10 install to select a drive to install Windows on, the list is empty. Any way I can get Windows 10 to recognize the m.2?

Build:

- Asus z170-a
- 6700k
- 750w PSU
- H100i
- Msi 1070 gtx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to get Windows 10 to recognize it.

In the BIOS:

- Hit F5 for Default settings.
- Hit F7 for Advanced settings.
- Under the Advanced tab change:

  - Onboard Devices Configuration:

    - SATA Mode Configuration -> M.2

Comment: in my bios there is the option of m.2 PCH SATA and m.2 PCH PCIE (apparently PCIE is faster). The newest Windows installer recognizes my m.2 but my old DVD did not.

Answer (score 1):

You will need [Intel Rapid Storage Technology](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/rapid-storage-technology.html) for the Windows 10 setup to recognize the M.2 device. Once you download it, extract it onto your bootable device, then boot from the device.

Comment: Does it what matter what directory I extract it into?

Comment: @GlobalJim Nope. Can be the root, a subfolder, etc.

Comment: @GlobalJim Did it work? If not, is there anything I can help with?

Comment: it wont let me extract the files onto my Windows 10 flash drive.

Comment: @GlobalJim What do you mean? Can you show some screenshots?